# ViewModel Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, viewmodel

I want to load a screen with a ViewModel depending on the option selected.

I thought Inheritance would be key here, as a lot of the properties are the same. Below is an extract of the code that I have.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bool isHandheld = false;

        var pdv1 = isHandheld == true ? new PDVHH() : new PDV();

        txtCaseID.Text = pdv1.CaseID;
        txtPDV.Text = isHandheld == true ? pdv1.PDVString : string.Empty;
        txtPDVHH.Text = isHandheld == true ? pdv1.PDVHHString : string.Empty;

    }
}

class basePDV
{
    public string CaseID { get; set; }
}

class PDV : basePDV
{
    public string PDVString { get; set; }
}

class PDVHH : basePDV
{
    public string PDVHHString { get; set; }
}
```

The error I am receiving is... "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'WindowsFormsApplication1.PDVHH' and 'WindowsFormsApplication1.PDV'"

I'm hoping someone can give me some guidance on a solution for this.

Comment: PDVHH and PDV are 2 different objects even if they inherit from the same class. Basic principle.

Comment: FYI, your `pdv1` will be of the type `PDV`.  Only sometimes will is also be of the type `PDVHH` so there's a good chance that down-casting the object to `PDVHH` will fail and you will be unable to access the (non-existent) property `PDVHHString`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I understand how ?: works, I was trying to use it to resolve my question. If there is another way, please help me.

Comment: Personally, I would go with composition over inheritance...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Answer (score 2):

Ok, your question is not really about inheritance or ViewModels but about how `?:` (the conditional operator) works.

The following will fix it:

```
var pdv1 = isHandheld == true ? (basePDV) new PDVHH() : (basePDV) new PDV();
```

While your code looks plausible, the docs say that you need a conversion between PDVHH and PDV, either direction, but the conversion to basePDV isn't considered.

When you can find a common name for PDVString and PDVHHString and implement it as a single property in the base class, it might work like you want. And even simpler. Note that `class PDV : basePDV {}` is Ok.

Comment: This doesn't resolve my problem as when trying to use either of the properties inside PDVHH or PDV, Visual Studio cannot see them. I am guessing this is because I am converting it to basePDV.

Comment: Which is the basic flaw in your solution. `var` isn't as flexible as it looks.

Comment: Would you be able to point me in the right direction for using the same screen with different ViewModels?

Comment: "same screen with different ViewModels" is not something I would even consider. Although the reverse (multiple Views for one ViewModel) is quite common.

Comment: Your example is simplified too much to give good advice. But ask yourself, why would a HandHeld device require a different ViewModel? Is the logic any different? We normally have different Views (markup) for different devices binding to the same abstracted ViewModel,

Comment: Oh ok, the business requirement is for the majority of the Handheld screen to be the same as one of the internal system screens. I thought by using a base class loading all of the same data and then add on the required fields (Hiding them from the screen if it is not required). Hope that makes sense

Comment: No, it seems to fit my proposal better: 1 ViewModel, and multiple Views that only show what they have to.

Answer (score 0):

The C# language specification distinguishes between three types of statements. In general you can have these statements:

labeled-statement - This is for a go-to statement

declaration-statement - This is for a variable declaration

embedded-statement - Which applies to all the remaining statements

In the if statement the body has to be embedded-statement, which explains why the first version of the code doesn't work.

if ( boolean-expression ) embedded-statement
if ( boolean-expression ) embedded-statement else embedded-statement

A variable declaration is declaration-statement, so it cannot appear in the body. If you enclose the declaration in brackets, you'll get a statement block, which is an embedded-statement (and so it can appear in that position).

```
var pdv1 = isHandheld == true ? new PDVHH() : new PDV(); is considered a declaration-statement.

//var pdv1 = isHandheld == true ? new PDVHH() : new PDV(); won't work but the following will

// The above is the equivalent of the below statement which will NOT work.
if (isHandheld)
      var pdv1 = new PDVHH();
else
      var pdv1 = new PDV();

if (isHandheld)
{
    var pdv1 = new PDVHH();
}
else
{
    var pdv1 = new PDV();
}
```

Comment: You can't use the `pdv1`s outside of the `{}` they're in. Not a solution.

Comment: Still a possible solution. He would just have to execute the assignments in the if branch where it checks if it is handheld.

Comment: Read the rest of the comments here, the core problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Verified that the issue was with the model.